# Segmentation fault attempting to print an Objective-C field in gdb

Tags: objective-c, debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault

In GDB I get a segmentation fault if I attempt to do the following:

```
print bg->top
```

The code looks a bit like this:

```
@interface Sprite : Object
{
@public
    int top;
    /* Other fields */
}
@end

bg = [Sprite load: "test.png"];
/* GDB is at a breakpoint after the above line */
```

The message I get is:

```
(gdb) print bg->top

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x6a7e3048 in libobjc-2!__objc_class_links_resolved () from C:\MinGW\bin\libobjc-2.dll
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(objc_lookup_class) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
```

Why is this?

I'm using the GNU Objective-C runtime and I'm not using GNUStep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how is 'bg' declared?
id bg or Sprite *bg

using 'id bg'
you must cast bg to the correct class,

```
(gdb) p bg->top
There is no member named top.

(gdb) p ((struct Sprite *)bg)->top
$1 = 0
```

using Sprite *bg

```
(gdb) p bg->top
$1 = 0
```

using GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.50.20110421-cvs
under linux, which version of gdb are you using?

is the Sprite class implemented separately in a DLL/library or
in the main application?

its possible it could be some manifestation of 
http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39465

Comment: I'm using `Sprite* bg` and my gdb version is 7.2 under windows using Mingw32.  `Sprite` is implemented in the main application.

Comment: does your application use *any* static libraries at all?

Comment: Yes - `-lobjc -lglfw -lSOIL -lopengl32`, why could that make a difference?  This happens for all Objective-C objects, not just `Sprite`.

Comment: @kragen that bug I linked to above has something to do with the mixing of shared library contstructors from .dll's and .a files, the constructors are used to tell the runtime about each class in the shared/static library, so the best I can recommend is try (even a simple test case) where you are using entirely dll's or entirely static libraries, (I notice you have libobjc.dll so thats probably the way to go)